# Extracting nodes and edges from osm data

Tags: openstreetmap, matlab

I am trying to extract the edges and nodes of a certain city from osm files and save them to a database. How can I accomplish this. I am not sure how much osm2po and osm2pgrouting tools are acceptable. I mean what is the standard procedure to get the graph. I mean when I use osm2po and tools like that they generate their own data structures. I mean they have this column called geometry of type multiline string and stuff. I am not sure if I should use this. Actually, I want to implement shortest path algorithm of my own.

I am not sure if osm is the only source to get such graph. Also, I want to plot the generated graph in matlab. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can find some MATLAB scripts to import openstreetmap files here:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35819-openstreetmap-functions
these include functions for plotting the map and network, as well as a routing example.